# Why do I get the error "You must have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 installed on your computer before proceeding." when installing Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010

I want to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I have downloaded `VsSDK_sfx.exe` from http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/E/D/8ED90A2C-8172-4FCA-B17B-C29C3F0A9732/VsSDK_sfx.exe

When I am trying to install, I am getting this error:

> Setup has found an error before Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK or one of its optional components.You need to restart the installer again.
>
> Error Type: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Sdk.Setup.Mossing PrerequisiteException.
>
> Errormessage: You must have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 installed on your computer before proceeding.

Comment: If you want help you need to post the installation error log or at least the more information. You do understand that `VsSDK_sfx.exe` isn't even Visual Studio 2010 right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you have is for the SDK (software development kit). If you are looking for Visual Studio 2010 the development environment you can go here for the express version:

[VS 2010 express editions](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express)

For Visual Studio 2012 you can start here:

[MS Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/default.aspx)

Comment: @Amit0440 The SDK has prerequisites, like having Visual Studio 2010 installed prior which is what the error in your initial question is saying...